# plot corner of ternary plot only

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, ggtern

I am trying to plot just the corner of a ternary plot (where all my data reside) but cannot seem to figure it out using the `scale_"X"_continuous(limits=c(0,20))` , with "X" being set to T, L and R respectively.

[dropbox link to dummy data set](https://www.dropbox.com/s/apqvf4ag51zvk8b/dummy.csv?dl=0)

Here's what the figure I'm making looks like.  I'd like to plot that smallest triangle, if possible.  I assume I'd incorrectly defining the limits, because I recieve an error stating "Error: Invalid Ternary Limits, Each Point Must Sum to Unity..."
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `scale_X_continous()` limits arguments seems to need values < 1 to work. This does what you want:

```
 ggtern(data=dummy,aes(x=x,y=y,z=z,col=type)) +
 geom_point() + 
 scale_T_continuous(limits=c(0,.2))+ 
 scale_L_continuous(limits=c(0,.2))+ 
 scale_R_continuous(limits=c(0.8,1))
```

Comment: Many thanks!  I can't believe I didn't try that. I REALLY felt like I'd googled my brains out there....

Comment: I guess I should make some kind of check to accept cases that sum to 100.